# How create theme with Liferay-look-and-feel.xml file

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I created a theme and a Liferay-look-and-feel.xml file with two color-schemes. I deploy the theme, install it, but when I run it on my website, I receive the follow message "There are no configurable plugins for this app.".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by the message you're getting you are in "App Manager". This is good, it means your theme is installed and ready for use. To use your theme, you must configure each site with the theme you've installed. In Liferay, each site is capable of having their own look and data.

To change a sites look and feel, follow the following steps:

1. Navigate to the site you want to modify.
2. In the upper right hand, select "Admin", then "Pages".
3. Here, you should see a list of themes and the color schemes.
4. Select your theme and the color scheme you desire.
5. Hit save on the right hand side near the navigation.

When you return to your site you should see your new theme.